# Accessing the RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item on controller in Sitecore 9

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api

I'm trying to get the current item for filter search value. When im trying to access the `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item` it showing some kind of error. Please find my screen shot below.
1. I'm Getting error because of postback in case if it is, How to resolve this without ajax?

[image: Controller screen]

[image: Views Screen]

Error Message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Attempt to retrieve context object of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext' from empty stack.
  Source=Sitecore.Mvc
  StackTrace:
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Common.ContextService.Peek[T]()
   at Molina.Project.Microsites.Web.Controllers.MicroSites.HopeLocationDropOff.LocationDropOffController.GetLocationInfo(String SearchString) in C:\Molina\Mohamed\Project\Microsites\Molina.Project.Microsites.Web\Controllers\MicroSites\HopeLocationDropOff\LocationDropOffController.cs:line 23
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2()
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes, DataSource Item not mapped properly thats why it is failed to get Sitecore Item.